# Image Preview in a Listbox

Tags: delphi, image, listbox, preview

How can I display a preview (almost like a hint) of an image when I hover the mouse over an item in a listbox of filenames? I've tried showing a form and loading the image, but when the preview form shows, I lose focus for the listbox which means that when I move the mouse, the preview image does not change when I go to the next item in the list.

Thanks, Pieter.

---

I have, based on the answer from  TOndrej, tried to implement a custom THintWindow, but the Canvas.StretchDraw does not draw the bitmap sent as a parameter. Any ideas why not? Text is displayed normally.

```
procedure TFormMain.DisplayPreview(HintImage: TBitmap);
var
  CustomHint: THintWindow;
  Rect: TRect;
  MousePoint: TPoint;
begin
  *{
    Based on Source: http://www.chami.com/tips/delphi/112996D.html
  }*
  GetCursorPos(MousePoint);
  with Rect do
    begin
      // set the position and size of the hint window
      Left   := MousePoint.X;
      Top    := MousePoint.Y;
      Right  := Left + 50;
      Bottom := Top + 25;
    end;

  CustomHint := THintWindow.Create(Self);
  try
    with CustomHint do
      begin
        // set the background color
        //Color := clNone;
        **Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect, HintImage);**
        ActivateHint(Rect, 'Hint');
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        //
        // perform your tasks here
        // before closing the hint window
        //
        Sleep(500);
        ReleaseHandle;
      end;

  finally
    if Assigned(CustomHint) then
      CustomHint.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it seems you want a custom hint window. To do this you should write a new `THintWindow` descendant and either set it globally to the whole application by assigning your new class to the `HintWindowClass` global variable in `Forms` unit, or write your own listbox descendant in which you will handle `CM_HINTSHOW` message and assign your new hint window class to `HintInfo.HintWindowClass`. (HintInfo points to a record passed to your control in the `CM_HINTSHOW` message by the VCL.)

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you displaying your preview form like a dialog (Modal Window) if yes then change it to non modal window.

2) Remember to set focus back to your parent window once the preview form shows up, that way your parent form that has the listbox has the focus and it will pass the mouse move events to the listbox.

Best Regards.